# My SQL database structure & associated procedures backup & restore

Tags: mysql

I want to duplicate a database structure including associated procedures from one machine to another, no data duplication required. How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: Add some level of details or your question will be soonly closed as "too broad". What is the source and target environments (OS, MySQL version) ? Is this a oneshot operation or should it be done on a regular basis? Is this a manual operation or should it be automated ? Do you want to do it from console commands, or PHPmyadmin, or MySQL workbench, or anything else? That kind of details.

Comment: @Thomas, Thanks for response. This is a one shot operation. MySQL 5.7.15, OS is CentOS7. I need to do it once only manually from cmd line.